# How do I use spaces with my objShell.CurrentDirectory code?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

How can I fix this code so it works correctly? I think it has something to do with the spaces in "Start Menu". The problem comes when I run the file in another drive. For example my P: Drive

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
File = "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
objShell.CurrentDirectory = File
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variables can't be just notated in the path string. You have to use the Shell object method below (ExpandEnv...) to obtain the Environment variable.

This should do what I assume you're trying to do to-date.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"): appdata = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
File = appdata & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
objShell.CurrentDirectory = File
Wscript.Echo objShell.CurrentDirectory
```